# How can I programatically generate Db docs for Oracle (SQL Developer)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer I can generate HTML Docs describing the database tables complete with triggers and indexes very nicely by right clicking a database and clicking "Generate Db Document" (translated).

I would like to do this as part of a build script in my main project and was wondering if there is a way to run this programatically? (without resorting to macro software haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best source of information about SQL Developer is the website of Jeff Smith, the SQL Developer Product Owner.
I think he's doing a great communication job about the tool.

It's mentioned in the comment of [this topic](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/08/db-doc-enhancements-for-oracle-sql-developer-v4/) that it's not possible for the moment.

Also you can check the Oracle SQL Developer exchange which has a dedicated [feature request](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=43135:7:::NO:RP,7:P7_ID:26281) about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't suppose you could point me in the direction of a better way to achieve what I want? (scripted docs) Is there a "standard way" to do this that I don't know about? Unrelated to the question but I'd appreciate it

Comment: Doxygen seems to be an interesting tool but I'm not sure it can handle PL/SQL for now. Otherwise there are some other dedicated tools (e.g. https://dbmstools.com/pl-sql-documentation-tools) but I did not try them.